# Sudo: No password for certain command for everybody (including domain users)

Tags: sudo

I want to allow the execution of a mount script for everybody. I'm usually working with a domain user. While allowing the usage of sudo for my user works, I can't disable the password prompt for a certain command.

My sudoers file is unmodified, except for an additional line at the end:

`%domain^users ALL = PASSWD: ALL, NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/mount_synology`

I executed `sudo -k` to delete cached credentials, then I tried `/usr/local/bin/mount_synology` but I still get a password prompt. Any idea what's wrong? Also, how would I go about adding multiple allowed commands?

Comment: Does your script call another program that requires superuser privileges (such as mount) ? Perhaps adding all users to a group that has permissions would be better.

Comment: @IanB. Found the problem, shouldn't have used sudo for the mount command inside the script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem (should have posted the contents of the script itself, that would have helped).

Sudoing the `mount_synology` didn't issue the password prompt. It was the `sudo mount` inside the script. But since I call the script with `sudo` there was no need to sudo the mount command.

After removing the `sudo` in the script, it worked :)